# How do I update DataGridView on parent form in C#

Tags: c#

How do I update a property on a parent form from a child form in C#?

Comment: I create the child utilizing: frm_AddEntry f_AddEntry = new frm_AddEntry();
            f_AddEntry.Show();

Comment: What is it that says that f_AddEntry is a child of your parent form?

Comment: You are correct, the from is not a child. It is another form in the application. I suppose my question should be how do I edit the properties of one form from another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is no parent child relation between the forms then you could have a look at the accepted answer to this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176682/access-of-public-method-between-forms/4176767#4176767

In this question it is about accessing a public method in an other form, so you could easily change that to a property.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is create an event which the child control raises and the parent can then consume or not as needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
YourParentForm p = (YourParentForm)child.MdiParent;
p.YourProperty = "YourValue";
```

Comment: This can be used if you have a MDIContainer as the parent form and that you set the MdiParent property when you create the child forms.

Answer (score 0):

//u can do it using a peroperty :

public static string update
{
     get{return textbox1.text}
     set{textbox1.text=value }
}

Answer (score 0):

Change the `dataGridView1`'s '`Modifiers`' property to Internal,

then you can access it using something like this `((frm01)this.Parent.Parent.Parent).dataGridView1`