# Using Another Form to Show Data with Checkboxes C#

Tags: c#, .net, forms, winforms, checkbox

I'm using WinForms. I have 2 forms, Form 1 and Form 2. In Form 2 i have multiple checkboxes. How do I check if anyone of those checkboxes in form2 is checked?
Each checkbox in form 2 displys a differnet message in form 1. Example, If i open form 2 and check the first checkbox, and close form2. In form1 a message should display in a label.

**Form1**

```
 private Form2 frm2; 

    private void Open_frm_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
        frm2.ShowDialog(); 
    }


    private void show_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (frm2.checkBox1.Checked)
        {
            lbl_checkbx1.Text = "Hello";
        }
    }
```

[image]

**Error**

When i run the program, click on open Form2 button and check Message 1 checkbox and close from 2 then click show button. I get this error.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access Of Public Method Between Forms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176682/access-of-public-method-between-forms)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Form1 you would have this:

```
var form2 = new Form2();
form2.ShowDialog();

if (form2.Check1Checked)
{
    label1.Text = "Check1 is checked on form2";
}

if (form2.Check2Checked)
{
    label2.Text = "Check2 is checked on form2";
}

form2.Dispose();
```

On `Form2` set up some properties to expose the checkbox's checked value.  This way you don't have to expose the entire control.

```
// C# v5.0 or earlier
public bool Check1Checked
{
    get { return checkBox1.Checked; }
}
// C# v6.0
public bool Check2Checked => checkBox2.Checked;
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to pass form1 as a parameter of form2 and then just linking the form2 checkboxes with Form1 labels.

```
public class Form2 { 
  private readonly Form1 _form1;

  public Form2(Form1 form1) {
    _form1 = form1; 
  }
```

}

and from Form1,

```
private void Open_frm_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 frm2 = new Form2(this);
        frm2.ShowDialog(); 
    }
```

Comment: How would i know if one of the checkboxes is checked in form2?